# Issue in using __repr__ function to return a non-string value from a method in a class

Tags: python

I have a class that contains an `__init__` method, a method which changes the init value and a `__repr__` function that wants to print out the adjusted value

The draft of the code is as follows

```
class Workflow: 
    def __init__(self, a): 
        self.a = a 
    
    def build(self):
        self.a += 1
        
    def __repr__(self): 
        value = self.build()
        return value

# Driver Code         
t = Workflow(1234) 
print(t)
```

And I got an error as follows

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[71], line 3
      1 # Driver Code         
      2 t = Workflow(1234) 
----> 3 print(t)

TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

What's the mistake that I have made?
In this case, if I want to print out the value that has beed changed by a method, how should I do that?

Comment: As it mentions, you are returning None from __repr__, which needs to return a string.  So you should back track to see why the value would None.  Think about what `build()` is doing and you might see the problem.

Comment: Hint: try to **read** the error message. Notice how it says that `__str__` returned something that was not a string? Did you try to define `__str__`, or `__repr__`? Which one do you suppose needs to be defined, in order for this to work? Why?

Comment: Second hint: it seems like your intent, was to call `build`, and then make `__repr__` return the value from the `build` call... right? So... what does `build` return, when it is called? (Do you see a `return` anywhere in that method?) Or, another way: "if I want to print out the value that has beed changed by a method" - well, **what did you change**? `self.a`, right? So....

Answer (score 1):

`build` does not return anything so the value variable will be None

For example you do it like this:

```
    def build(self):
        self.a += 1
        
    def __repr__(self): 
        self.build()
        return str(self.a)
```

**BUT**

it is better - and convention - that you use the `__str__` method here for readability:

```
    def __str__(self): 
        self.build()
        return str(self.a)

    def __repr__(self): 
        return "Workflow(" + str(self.a) + ")"
```

`__repr__` should be associated with how you construct an object in the init and you can use it for copy paste to create new objects.

Comment: While it's true that `__repr__` should return a string, the example requires `__str__` to be defined instead.

Comment: But I think underlying `__str__` just calls `__repr__` as fallback hence the error

Comment: Ah, good point. It happens that the fallback fails in the same way as if it hadn't been there :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Function `build` doesn't return anything thats why you got `None` in `value`
2. It is a bad idea to modify value of attribute `a` with `build` function in `__repr__` if you want to show current state.

   ```
   def __repr__(self):
       return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.a})"
   ```

   output

   ```
   Workflow(1234)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Hwow abouit this:

```
class Workflow:
def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a

def build(self):
    self.a += 1
    return self.a

def __repr__(self):
    value = self.build()
    return str(value)
```

## Driver Code

t = Workflow(1234)
print(t)